# What happens internally when std::move is called?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I wanted to know what exactly happens internally when we call std::move on an object.
For example:

```
class Holder {
    int* m_ptr;
    int m_size;
public:
    Holder(int size) : m_size(size),
        m_ptr(size ? new int[size] : 0) {
        cout << "Constructor\n";
    }
    ~Holder() {
        cout << "Destructor\n";
        delete[] m_ptr;
    }

    Holder(const Holder& other) {
        cout << "Copy Constructor\n";
        m_ptr = new int[other.m_size];
        std::copy(other.m_ptr, other.m_ptr + other.m_size, m_ptr);
        m_size = other.m_size;
    }

    void swap(Holder& other) noexcept {
        std::swap(this->m_ptr, other.m_ptr);
        std::swap(this->m_size, other.m_size);
    }

    Holder& operator=(const Holder& other) {
        cout << "Copy Assignment\n";
        Holder(other).swap(*this);
    }

    Holder(Holder&& other) : m_ptr(other.m_ptr), m_size(other.m_size) {
        cout << "Move Constructor\n";
        other.m_ptr = nullptr;
        other.m_size = 0;
    }

    Holder& operator=(Holder&& that) noexcept {
        cout << "Move Assignment\n";
        Holder(std::move(that)).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
};


Holder createHolder(int size) {
    return Holder(size);
}

int main(void) {
    Holder h = createHolder(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the output as when compiled with '`-fno-elide-constructors`':

```
Constructor
Move Constructor
Destructor
Move Constructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

Since we are returning from a function `createHolder` and the return object is on the stack, how does the `main` function still receives it? Not getting exactly what happens internally in memory.

Thanks.

Comment: Which part shouldn't be received?

Comment: I wanted to know what happens internally with respect to memory when we call std::move

Comment: But your code isn't calling `std::move` at all; move assignment operator isn't called.

Comment: Maybe you are really wondering how objects are returned by-value on the stack in typical calling conventions?

Answer (score 2):

`std::move` is a noop function that converts any kind of reference into an rvalue reference.  So it doesn't actually "do" anything, it just changes how it's argument is used.

```
template <class T> constexpr remove_reference_t<T>&& move(T&& t) noexcept;
    Returns: static_cast<remove_reference_t<T>&&>(t).
```

Comment: This answer the title, but not really the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

std::move  make your operator =, constructor is call correctly with what you defined in the Holder class

```
Holder(Holder&& other) : m_ptr(other.m_ptr), m_size(other.m_size) {
    cout << "Move Constructor\n";
    other.m_ptr = nullptr;
    other.m_size = 0;
}

Holder& operator=(Holder&& that) noexcept {
    cout << "Move Assignment\n";
    Holder(std::move(that)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

`Since we are returning from a function createHolder and the return object is on the stack, how does the main function still receives it?`
because your move constructor

you already copy pointer m_ptr(other.m_ptr) m_size(other.m_size) from
Holder(size) -> move to Holder object in return register on stack -> move to Holder h in main function

```
Constructor  -> of Holder(size);
Move Constructor -> Holder(size) move to Holder object in return register on stack
Destructor -> destructor of Holder(size)
Move Constructor -> from Holder object on stack -> Holder h in main
Destructor -> destructor of Holder object in return register
Destructor -> destructor of Holder h in main
```